# Finding the general solution of the given linear homogeneous differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is quite simple but I am having doubt :-
 I am asked to find out the general solution of the differential equation
 $(D^2- 4)y=0$ where $D=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

If I want to use hyperbolic function then I have its general solution to be

$y(x)= a \cosh 2x + b \sinh 2x$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Alternatively can I write the solution to be $y = ae^{2x}+ b e^{-2x}$ ? i.e using distinct and real roots $-2$ , $2$ ?

What relation does these two solution possess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember $\cosh x=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$ & $\sinh x=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$

Yes, you can write the general solution of $(D^2-4)y=0$ as follows
$$y=C.F.(\text{complementary function}) +P.I. (\text{particular integral})$$

$$C.F.=ae^{2x}+be^{-2x}$$
since the particular integral is $0$. hence, the solution is
$$y=ae^{2x}+be^{-2x}+0$$$$=ae^{2x}+be^{-2x}$$